# Questions About TVs—On Topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions about CRT TVs relevant in this SE community?

I certainly hope so because you better believe I have questions about CRTs!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes.

They're relevant, and they're barely used any more. I don't see why reason why they shouldn't be.

Also, we've had a tag for them, [crt-monitor](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crt-monitor), since almost the beginning of the site.

Comment: @BlackandWhite Link? Just because it's about something on-topic doesn't mean that the question itself is on-topic.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 CRT-Monitor and CRT-TV are quite different things. While the first is usually ment for computer usage (lets ignore professional AV stuff for a moment), the second is primary NOT a computer related device. It will need a certain computer specific, more important a retro computer specific question topic to make it relevant. Don't you think so?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5584/high-voltage-in-bell-of-crt-tube Could you take a look at this please?

Comment: CRT monitors are most definitely computer related devices. UHF TVs only insofar as they are used as monitors. Perhaps we need a TV tag.

Comment: @Chenmunka I tried to create a TV tag but had too low reputation to do so.

Answer (score 7):

General questions about TVs are probably not on-topic.  Questions like "How can I view digital broadcast TV on my old CRT TV" and "How do I connect this CRT TV to this old VCR" are really not related to retro-computing.

But questions about using TVs with retro computers would be.  Questions like "How can I hook up old computer model XYZ to my old CRT TV" and "Why are the colors different when I hook up a CRT TV to my computer via RF versus Composite?" are clearly on-topic.

There is also a gray area: "How can I fix this broken CRT TV?" might be on-topic or it might not, depending on whether the OP intends to use this TV with a computer once it's fixed.  If they don't explicitly say it's for a non-computing purpose I am inclined to give them the benefit of the doubt and call it on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

**No, they are not. At least not more than VCRs or Toilet plumbing.**

After all, this is about Retro *COMPUTING*, not *Retro Electronics* or *Radios from Yesteryear*.

Having said that, it depends of course on the specific question asked.

Looking for some replacement diodes in a HF circuitry is for sure not, but looking for the reasoning why many home computers are tuned for channel 3 or 4 might be.

Or more general: **A question about intrinsic workings of a TV set is not, while the same TV set in relation to a specific computer issue may qualify.**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72378/discussion-on-answer-by-raffzahn-questions-about-tvson-topic).